Why does the match/case statement not work with referenced pattern?
What's wrong with the fragment below?
color = ["black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white"]

code = "yellow"

match code:
    case color[0]:
        print("The color black is coded as 0.")
    case color[1]:
        print("The color black is coded as 1.")
    case color[2]:
        print("The color black is coded as 2.")
    case color[3]:
        print("The color black is coded as 3.")
    case color[4]:
        print("The color black is coded as 4.")
    case color[5]:
        print("The color black is coded as 5.")
    case color[6]:
        print("The color black is coded as 6.")
    case color[7]:
        print("The color black is coded as 7.")
    case color[8]:
        print("The color black is coded as 8.")
    case color[9]:
        print("The color black is coded as 9.")
    case _:
        print("No color to choose from.")

I get the syntax error at "case color[0]:". I'm using Python 3.13.
I've search around but found nothing about using a reference to an item of a list as a matching case pattern.

Python's structural pattern matching is not just a switch.

Would you not rather use color.index(code) ?

It looks like color should really be a dict that maps strings to code numbers (and possibly vice versa as well). Or perhaps an enum) would be more appropriate. Really, anything that avoids creating a huge match or if/elif block would be an improvement here.

This is an unnecessary use of Match-Case but if it was to be used then you need to appreciate pattern matching rather than a basic switch as in C etc. You could use:
color = ["black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray", "white"]

code = "yellow"

match code:
    case code if code == color[0]:
        print(f"The color {code} is coded as 0.")
    case code if code == color[1]:
        print(f"The color {code} is coded as 1.")
    case code if code ==color[2]:
        print(f"The color {code} is coded as 2.")
    case code if code == color[3]:
        print(f"The color {code} is coded as 3.")
    case code if code == color[4]:
        print(f"The color {code} is coded as 4.")
    case _:
        print("No color to choose from.")

which prints:
The color yellow is coded as 4.
    


This is daft. Why not just use an if/elif block and avoid all the extra boiler-plate? Or even better, just use a dict to look up the code.
